# I cant launch Intel X86_x64 AVD because VT-X is disabled

Tags: java, android-virtual-device

! Intel Visualisation Technology is enabled in BIOS (default settings)

I have a problem "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. VT-x is disabled in BIOS. Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings" when i'm trying to launch AVD

I'm sure that my CPU is supports VT-X. i saw specifications of my CPU (i5-4210U)

What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support.

Comment: Check the motherboard BIOS setting.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Virtual PC installed, if so it has already claimed the VT-X feature, and other programs can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Avast! AV by any chance?  If so, find the option "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" and turn it off.  Also, if you're looking to use this for Android development, you'll want to disable Hyper-V in Windows if it's enabled.

You could also try downloading/installing Inetl's standalone HAXM installer (found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)) to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried to install HAXM before, but got an error. This time the installation completed successfully :D